# How to make bar plot in plotly with two categories?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, bar-chart

I have such data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
dict(
    week=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3] * 2,
    layout=["classic", "classic", "modern", "modern"] * 3,
    response=["conversion", "exit"] * 6,
    cnt=[26, 23, 45, 34, 55, 44, 53, 27, 28, 25, 30, 34],))
```

And I need to get such barplot like in excel with plotly:
[image]

The main problem that I can not use two categoies. My code:

```
px.bar(
    data_frame=df,
    x='week',
    y='cnt',
    template='plotly_dark',
    color = 'layout'
)
```

and result:
[image]

But i cannot display information about "response" like in excel example

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that the most flexible way would be to use `go.Figure()` and then

```
fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=dfp['week'], y = dfp['cnt'], name = v))
```

for each value, `v`, in `['conversion - classic', 'conversion - modern', 'exit - classic', 'exit - modern']` like this:

```
fig = go.Figure()
for v in df['value'].unique():
    dfp = df[df['value']==v]
    fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=dfp['week'], y = dfp['cnt'], name = v))
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', template='plotly_dark')
fig.show()
```

### Plot:

[image]

As far as I can tell, this should resemble your Excel output pretty closely.

### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
dict(
    week=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3] * 2,
    layout=["classic", "classic", "modern", "modern"] * 3,
    response=["conversion", "exit"] * 6,
    cnt=[26, 23, 45, 34, 55, 44, 53, 27, 28, 25, 30, 34],))

df['value'] = df['response'] + ' - ' + df['layout']
df = df.sort_values('value')
# df2 = df.groupby(['value', 'week']).sum().reset_index().sort_values('value')

fig = go.Figure()
for v in df['value'].unique():
    dfp = df[df['value']==v]
    fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=dfp['week'], y = dfp['cnt'], name = v))
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', template='plotly_dark')
fig.show()
```